# I am trying include Probability (percent) ,Closedate standard fields in Test Opportunity creation class

Tags: apex, unit-test, opportunity

```
@isTest
public class TestCreateOppExtension  {
static testMethod void TestCreateOppExtension() {

     Account testAcct = new Account (Name = 'My Test Account');
     insert testAcct;
 Opportunity opp  = new Opportunity(Name ='sample Opp',
                            AccountID = testAcct.ID,
                            Type ='Medium',
                         //   Start_Date__c =System.today(),
                            CloseDate = '2017-08-07',
                            PM_I_Business_Field__c ='Leading Edge East',
                            Main_Group_GPH1__c ='BARC',
                            Customer_Group_ERP__c='Samsung',
                            Device__c='SAMSUNG LOGIC',
                            Node_Size__c='46nm',           
                            StageName = 'M0: Conception',
                            Status__c='Open',
                            Reason_PM_I__c='Quality',          
                            Sub_Reason__c='Superior Material to Competitors',
                            Probability ='10',
                            Monthly_Progress__c='Green'            
                            );

  insert  opp ;

  System.assertEquals(opp .StageName, 'M0: Conception');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Name, 'sample Opp');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Type, 'Medium');
 // System.assertEquals(opp .Start_Date__c ,'2017-07-25');
  System.assertEquals(opp .CloseDate,'2017-08-07');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Customer_Group_ERP__c, 'Samsung');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Device__c, 'SAMSUNG LOGIC');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Node_Size__c, '46nm');
  System.assertEquals(opp .PM_I_Business_Field__c, 'Leading Edge East');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Reason_PM_I__c, 'Quality');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Sub_Reason__c, 'Superior Material to Competitors'); 
 System.assertEquals(opp .Probability,'10%');
  System.assertEquals(opp .Monthly_Progress__c, 'Green');   

}
}
```

I am getting the below errors:

> Invalid initial expression type for field Opportunity.Probability,
>   expecting: Decimal'  and 'Invalid initial expression type for field
>   Opportunity.CloseDate, expecting: Date'.

Comment: you are assigning all the fields as string values. you should set the values with the corresponding data types..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning different value to different datatype. Closedate is date type and you are assigning string. And Probability is decimal type and you assigning string.

Replace your lines with this accordingly :

CloseDate = date.valueOf( '2017-08-07' )
Probability = 10